# Failed to save MyContactComp.cmp: No COMPONENT named markup://lighting:outputfield found

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-outputfield

when i am using to show data using ourtputfield its not allowing to save the component file. error message is below

```
 Failed to save MyContactComp.cmp: No COMPONENT named markup://lighting:outputfield found 


    <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.contactList}" var="contact">
            <lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{!contact.Id}" objectApiName="contact">
                <div class="slds-box slds-theme_default">
                    <lighting:outputfield fieldName="Name" />
                    <lighting:outputfield fieldName="Phone" />
                    <lighting:outputfield fieldName="Email" /> 


                </div>
            </lightning:recordViewForm>
        </aura:iteration>
    </p>
```

and when i am using direct {!contact.Name}  {!contact.Email} its showing data with bad formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is `lightning:outputfield`

not `lighting:outputfield`. you missed 'n'

check here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:outputField/example

Comment: Yes @Ratan.Nice catch :)

Comment: @cloudZigZag no problem